# Angular 2 calling a method after file browsing

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build a file upload method in Angular 2.
This would be the template:

`<input type="file" (click)="upload(value)">`

The problem is that the method starts on click way before a file is selected and passed to the value, getting an undefined instead. How do I do make the event wait for a file to be selected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call upload method on change of file input

```
<input #file type="file" (change)="upload(file.files)">
```

Comment: I figured it out just now, thanks!
How do you pass the file to the method btw? I thought a simple value was enough...